# Base Changing Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To change a number representation to another base, from given number in base 10 the algorithm is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Base_conversion).

I am trying to understand the intuition, why only the remainder is saved?

Answer (score 1):

If we take the example in your link, we find that $123_{10} = 4 + 17\cdot 7 = 4 + (3+2\cdot 7)\cdot 7 = 4 + 3\cdot 7 + 2\cdot 49 = 234_7$.

Comment: why we only count the reminders?

Comment: everything is reduced to remainders and powers of 7.